# como quitar estos espacios que se forman entre palabras en html y css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: como quitar estos espacios que se forman entre palabras en html y css?]

Hola al ejecutar un codigo de html con css aparecen estos espacios entre palabras y quisiera saber como puedo quitarlos y hacer que el texto no se vea con esos espacios

Comment: Aparece ese espacio porque el texto está justificado, mira la propiedad text-align de CSS

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta necesita más detalles, debes agregar un [mcve]. No podemos adivinar el código solo con ver una imagen.

Comment: Por favor, comparta su código para poder buscar el fallo y corregirlo. Gracias.